# Find the order of the distribution $\langle u,\phi\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\partial^k\phi(1/k)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Find the order of the distribution $u$ in $\mathscr{D}^\prime((0,\infty))$ 
 $$\langle u,\phi\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\partial^k\phi(1/k)$$

I guess it does not have finite order, but I have no idea to show that

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention it. It is supposed to be a distribution in $\mathscr{D}^\prime((0,\infty))$

Comment: Well, the definition of "finite order"  is "order $n$ for some $n$". What's the definition of "order $n$"?

Comment: $u$ has order n, if for every compact $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, there is a real number $C_K\geq 0$ such that $$|<u,\phi>|\leq C\displaystyle\sum_{|\alpha|\leq n}sup |\partial^k \phi|$$

Comment: And the least n satisfies above condition, is the order of $u$

Comment: What order does $u$ have on $(1/(k+1/2), \infty)$?

Comment: Ok. Now given $n$, there exists $\phi\in C^\infty_c((0,\infty))$ with $\partial^(n+1)\phi(1/(n+1))=1$, and if the support of $\phi$ is a small enough neighborhood of $1/(n+1)$ you  have $\partial^k\phi(1/k)=0$ for all $k\ne n+1$...

Comment: Sorry, I still cannot understand where leads to a contradiction.

Comment: The order of $u$ on an interval containing $x=1/k$ but not $x=1/(k+1)$ is $k$. If $U$ and $V$ are open sets with $U \subseteq V$ then the order on $V$ is at least the order on $U$.